# How to connect several "IF" formulas together?

Tags: apex, formula

I have got 5 fields each filled by a CASE formula related to the same picklist field; unfortunately the formula was to Long to have it in one field!

Only one of the 5 fields could have a value, the other four are empty.

Now I want to match These five fields together to on field using several IF formulas:

```
IF( Class_part1__c  <> "",  Class_part1__c , 
 IF( Class_part2__c  <> "",  Class_part2__c , 
 IF( Class_part3__c  <> "",  Class_part3__c , 
 IF( Class_part4__c  <> "",  Class_part4__c , 
 IF( Class_part5__c  <> "",  Class_part5__c , 
""
)))))
```

The Syntax Check says:

> "Error: Compiled formula is too big to execute (64.960 characters).
>   Maximum size is 5.000 characters"

But when I count myself, I only used 236 characters
What did I wrong ? 
Is there an alternative to solve this?

Comment: what is the data type of all these field..  Class_part1__c and others

Comment: The Field Typ is:  Formula (Text)

Comment: All the referenced formulas are added together when calculating the formula size.